How to iterate through formbuilder.group controls?
TypeScript
formGroup = this.fb.group({});

constructor(private readonly formBuilder: UntypedFormBuilder){}

ngOnInit() { this.setControls(); }


settControls() {
 this.formGroup.addControl('name', this.fb.control('', Validators.required));
 this.formGroup.addControl('age', this.fb.control('', Validators.required));
 this.formGroup.addControl('alias', this.fb.control('', Validators.required));
}

HTML
<ng-container *ngFor="let control of formGroup.controls">
  //show some formcontrol or component
 <input type="text" [formControlName]="control.name" class="form-control">
</ng-container>

I have tried ngFor but that doesn't work because form builder group is an object not an array. I know there is a formarray but that is not the way to go.
How do I iterate though the form group controls?

Controls is of type
controls: ɵTypedOrUntyped<TControl, TControl, {
    [key: string]: AbstractControl<any>;
}>

hence you will have to use keyvalue pipe to iterate over it
<ng-container *ngFor="let control of formGroup.controls | keyvalue">
    {{ control.key }}   // control name
    {{ control.value }} // control value, this is not actual value of control itself              
                        // this is a property provided by pipe to access value of object which should be of type formControl
                        // in order to get actual value of control, you must use control.value.value
</ng-container>

